# USB Drive Corrupted and Write Protected

Tags: usb-flash-drive, filesystem-corruption, write-protect

So my USB drive fell out of my Mac whilst I was saving some stuff. I plugged it back in but I was told that 'MacOS could not fix this device'. I plugged it into my windows machine and attempted to do a Full Format, however I am told that the disk is write protected. Here's what the main directory on it looks like: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNIGN.png), and what is shown when I try to format it: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMpXp.png)

I really can't afford to buy another stick of this size, is there anything that I can do to format it again? I was at least smart and made a backup of the data (AFTER scanning for viruses!)

Many Thanks

Comment: Have looked at other answers but none of them have sorted my issue

Answer (score 0):

[This page from EaseUS](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/format-a-write-protected-usb-flash-drive.html) offers a possible solution: change the registry key `HLKM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies` attribute `WriteProtect` value to `0`, re-mount the device, and try formatting it again.

(Note: This solution turns out to be listed, though not particularly highlighted, in the suggested duplicate.)